# Instant WordPress setups on Unix

Tags: wordpress, automation

Does anyone know of a way to instantly setup WordPress on a unix box? I know there is an 'Instant Wordpress' for a Windows environment but any for unix?

I guess the idea would be to instantly setup a wordpress site and configure the themes and plugins so that the site is ready to for a user to use after signing up.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the big hosting companies using a custom bash script to preinstall WordPress when provisioning a new hosting account or they offer a "one click install".

If your running Debian or Ubuntu you can use the [WordPress package maintained by Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wordpress).  Then it's as easy as `apt-get install wordpress`

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress MU](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_MU) maybe?

Yes, that link is outdated, but it gives the general overview of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like Instant Install? It's like a one-click installer for a variety of blogging platforms/CMS's.

http://instantinstall.org/